# cannot reference main form code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have 3 user controls and a main form and I can reference the user controls and use methods from the main form just fine:

```
Dim ReviewPanel As New ReviewPanel
Controls.Add(ReviewPanel)
ReviewPanel.BringToFront()
ReviewPanel.Go(-8, 0)
```

But referencing from the user control to the main form doesn't work properly:

```
Private Sub SelectionPanelClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click, picCover.Click, lblTitle.Click
    Dim _Main As New Form1
    _Main.DisplayReview()
End Sub
```

The code still runs fine; I can add messageboxes in the main form method and they'll still show up. However, nothing visually happens like a label won't update with the username.

I've tried to solve it and find workarounds but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ParentForm()` property and cast it to Form1:

```
' ... in your UserControl ...
Dim frm As Form = Me.ParentForm
If Not IsNothing(frm) AndAlso TypeOf frm Is Form1 Then
    Dim f1 As Form1 = DirectCast(frm, Form1)
    f1.DisplayReview()
End If
```